# Does anyone have a datasheet for the AMS FUA78MG IC?

Tags: integrated-circuit

While repairing a turn coordinator indicator, its gyro motor wasn’t spinning. When powered, only the red flag would disappear.  I figured later that the FUA78MG wasn’t working (goes to gyro motor and does not produce output to run gyro motor.) Does anyone have any datasheets or info about this IC?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This site](https://www.americanmicrosemi.com/product/otheralphanumerical-listingf/FUA78MG/) claims to have the FUA78MG for sale, but gives no details.

It does, however, have photos.  The ICs in the photo are marked "UA78MG."

Data on the UA78MG four terminal variable voltage regulator can be found in [this Fairchild data book.](http://www.bitsavers.org/components/fairchild/_dataBooks/1982_Fairchild_Linear_Division_Products.pdf)

From page 2-85:

[image]

The package and pinout are different, but I think the function is the same.  The "wings" on your IC would go to "common" and would be connected to a heat sink (as it appears in your photos.)

There are four functional pins on your IC, plus the wings.

You'll have to do some checking, but I think this is your chip.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info! I had a feeling that it must be some sort of voltage regulator given that it accepts voltage from 12-30V and has two pots, most likely for current and Voltage control I guess. In that case I think this should be a possible drop in replacement: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/324453482864?&shqty=1&isGTR=1#shId

Comment: Also on the prior site it is too costly and from the photos it is the same item you have mentioned and I found on eBay.

Comment: Yeah.  That site has insane prices.  The one you found on eBay looks right.